# How to use JAXB with springMvc project?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jaxb

I met a problem when developing a Spring MVC + Hibernate + JPA project, I wanted to turn an .xml file into a Java object with JAXB. this is a job very easy to do in a java simple project, but when I tried to do in this project spring mvc I had an exception of type "file not found exception" But the path to this file is right and what is shown because when I took this path and I put it in the browser address bar I get the xml file!

Comment: If you want to access a file from Java code in a webapp, best bet is to put it on the classpath and read it as a resource. My guess is you have it as a web static file and trying to access it via a File, which most likely won't be the path you are expecting. For better help please provide more information on your project structure, the code trying to access the file, and anything else you might feel is relevant. If you asked a better question, I bet you'd have a couple answers already. This is a fairly easy problem to solve, given there is enough information

Comment: Please copy-paste some code; where are you referencing the file? Are you using absolute/relative path? Relative to what? Can you link some example code from the web where this approach works?

Comment: What about JAXB plugin for your build tool, Maven, Gradle what have you?